# Database drilling down and across

Tags: database, database-design, data-warehouse

Can someone explain the terms of drilling down and drilling across to me I need to illustrate them both using ROLAP query code or pseudo code. I have tried researching about it but I find it complicated to understand, if someone could explain or point me in the right direction I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Drill down and Drill across are terms generally used in the reporting tool. The idea is that the report may show your fact table summarized and you can drill down for more details. I.e. the fact table holds salary costs on employee level. The report however is by default summed up to company level. Then you can in the report drill down, i.e. ask the reporting tool to show you the records it used to sum upp to the row you are looking at. This could mean that you i.e. dbl click on the company and are shown the salary cost per department, dbl click on a department and are shown salary cost per employee.

Drill across is a feature where the reporting tool lets you get data from another fact table, i.e. when you show the salary cost for an employee you could drill across to another fact table holding other information on that employee.

There are plenty of variation in how the tools implement these features and what they mean by them, but the general principals could be found here, as explained by Kimbal:
[Drilling Down, Up, and Across](http://www.kimballgroup.com/1996/03/01/drilling-down-up-and-across/)